# How to create delete function with jsp and mysql

Tags: java, jsp

im trying to a create a course table with crud
function.

So this is a simple page i want to create with the following function

1. Create Course
2. Edit Course
   3.Delete Cou
3. Update Course

Comment: Why is this work being done in the JSP at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the above has been resolved by change the input parameter